# magic imports in Python

Tags: python, class, dynamic

Edit: I should have specified I'm (stuck) working w/ Python 2, but would be interested to see how this could be tackled in either 2 or 3

**The scenario:**
I have a package called `shapes`.

I have a module in `shapes` called `factory` which has a `ShapeClassFactory` class.
This class can be passed a string, and it will look in a remote database for data and use that to dynamically define a class, which it returns.

shapes.py:

```
from .factory import ShapeClassFactory
__all__ = ['ShapeClassFactory']
```

In practice this package may be used in a variety of other packages & scripts, like so:

```
from shapes import ShapeClassFactory

Circle = ShapeClassFactory("Circle")
Rect = ShapeClassFactory("Rect")

myCircle = Circle(r=5, fill='red')
mySquare = Rect(x=5, y=5, fill=None)
```

**The problem:**
The above is all fine.  However, I would love to be able to write the `shapes` package in such a way that it could be used like so:

```
from shapes import Circle, Rect

myCircle = Circle(r=5, fill='red')
mySquare = Rect(x=5, y=5, fill=None)
```

...the idea being that if the member isn't found in `shapes`, it uses `ShapeClassFactory` to try and generate it.

The difficulty is that the available classes basically aren't known until requested, so a predefined list of class names won't help.

I don't mind throwing an `ImportError` if `ShapeClassFactory` fails to build a class -- but is such a thing even possible?

Comment: The import statement will run the module being imported, and then pull out the requested names. There's no way to know beforehand what names will be requested. Basically, you can't do this without doing something like patching `__import__` (maybe with meta hooks?), and you really shouldn't do that. For example, what does dir(shapes) do? The proper way to do this is what you've already done.

Comment: If the number of possible generated classes is fairly small, you could generate every one of them in the namespace of `shapes`. That would also be a standard and reasonable way to do this.

Comment: One of the main reasons I'm using generated classes is I want to avoid having to update the package if a new Shape is defined in the remote database, so defining a list of accepted classes isn't really a solution for this case.

Comment: You can actually have those classes update automatically. I'll write an answer assuming you have a function `get_shape_names` which queries the database.

Comment: This is an intriguing question. My initial reaction is that the factory setup you already have is not bad. Sure, it kinda feels on the verbose side for Python, but then again, it's still just one additional line per "dynamic import", so in practical terms, it's not horrible. And it has the benefit that the implementation is straightforward and easy to understand. That is always worth something, and shouldn't be thrown away lightly!

Comment: But doing things the way you *wish* them to be seems like a fun challenge, and seems like it *ought* to be possible in Python. I agree with most of what Jeremy said, but I think hacking on the import system shouldn't be avoided if you are up for the challenge, especially in Python 3. I say this because Python 3's `importlib` was purposely designed to be more flexible and easier to work with (to achieve your own special purposes) than Python 2's import machinery.

Comment: @JohnY agreed, what's there now is working well enough (and has been for a while), but it does seem like it _ought_ to be possible to do `from shapes import Circle` -- it feels much less clunky, as an interface. It also feels more like the way it _should_ work, even if the implementation requires a bit of black magic.

It's also freaking out my linter as-is, which is part of what got me thinking about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by automatically constructing all possible objects in the `shapes` namespace on initialization, as long as there aren't too many possible classes and the cost of initializing the classes up-front isn't too heavy. You would use code like this in shapes.py:

```
from .factory import ShapeClassFactory

__all__ = ['ShapeClassFactory']

def get_shape_names():
    """Returns all valid shapes that can be passed in to ShapeClassFactory"""
    return ['Circle', 'Rect']  # your own code should query the database

for name in get_shape_names():
    globals()[name] = ShapeClassFactory(name)
    __all__.append(name)
```

Comment: The trouble with this is that there are potentially dozens of Classes available, but typically only 2 to 4 used in a single module or script.

Because there is a significant cost in both the database queries and the class construction itself, I would like to only have to generate the classes that have been requested.

Comment: You might be able to offload the cost in class construction to instantiation. In other words, using instance variables defined within `__init__` rather than class variables. This would mean you only need one database query to get the list of possible shapes, and all other queries happen during instantiation.

Comment: I don't feel good about the idea of defining all attributes at the instance level -- besides that not being practical (ie. I want some classmethods), it feels like that code would be both a step backwards in readability and maintainability.  It also feels like a potential memory glut when working with large numbers of instances.